# loop through specific dataframe cell

Tags: r

here is my problem:
I have n dataframes (df1,df2,df3,df4,dn)
from each dataframe, I would like to extract the value of the same cell: [2,3] and store it for later

I though this would work:

```
for (i in 1:n){
assign(paste0("v",i),get(paste0("df",i,"[2,3]")
}
```

but get is trying to get an object rather than the value of a cell (giving an error).
Is there a function to do what I need?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you put your dataframes into a list, you can use lapply and avoid the messiness of control variables and assign/get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the `get` can be - i.e. `get` the whole object 'df`i`' and extract the values based on `i,j` indexing.  If we do `get("dfi[2,3]")`, it wouldn't work because there is no object named as that

```
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
    assign(paste0("v", i), get(paste0("df", i))[2,3]
}
```

---

As a small reproducible example

```
> data(mtcars)
> get("mtcars[1,2]")
Error in get("mtcars[1,2]") : object 'mtcars[1,2]' not found
> get("mtcars")[1,2]
[1] 6
```

Comment: Many thanks! That's it! I was close to go mental :)